# VBA Excel 2013 form closes when selecting from ComboBox

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

Can anyone see an issue in this block of code.  I had no issues in 2010, but seem to be running into a lot when running VBA in 2013.

I have a control form that is activated from an excel sheet, which has several options, then this form is opened (form those options).  The form opens, but when this first combobox selection is activated the form closes and essentially crashes.

```
Public Sub cmbSelectAccount_DropButtonClick()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\xxxxxx\Desktop\New folder\accounts.xlsx"

  Sheets("Accounts").Activate
  ActiveSheet.Range("a2:a199").Select

  Me.cmbSelectAccount.List = Worksheets("Accounts").Range("a2:a199").Value
  myAccount = Me.cmbSelectAccount.Value

  Workbooks("Accounts").Close
End Sub
```

If I step through the code it works flawlessly.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you activating and then selecting the range but never using the selection?  Seem like you can delete those two lines and speed up your code a little.

Comment: I should explain, the code seems to work and "has worked".  It's just that now if I click the original sheet (button in excel), it opens the controller form, which opens another form.  The form with the combobox works when ran through VBA, but just closes when activating the dropbutton click when used through the forms -- if that makes sense.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you upload your workbook in say www.wikisend.com. Let me test it in Excel 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (**UNTESTED**)

```
Public Sub cmbSelectAccount_DropButtonClick()
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\xxxxxx\Desktop\New folder\accounts.xlsx")

    DoEvents

    Me.cmbSelectAccount.List = wb.sheets("Accounts").Range("a2:a199").Value

    DoEvents

    myAccount = Me.cmbSelectAccount.Value

    wb.Close (False)
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately, form still closes when dropButton Click initializes.

Comment: ok let me get hold of office 2013... gimme 20 odd minutes. I have a feeling, I know why this might be happening. Let me test it before I post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

there are a few quirks with Sheets vs Worksheets in Excel, and maybe in 2013 they tried to fix them.  I'd try changing your 2 references to sheets and worksheets to all possible combinations, starting first with sheets, sheets   then worksheets worksheets,  then worksheets sheets

Comment: I will give it a shot and let you know.

Comment: Good advice.  This does not seem to change the outcome though.